# How can I ensure a Unity game continues to run in RAM, even if the disk it loaded from is removed?

Tags: unity, windows, memory

I'd like to make a game with Unity, put the build with all the data on a USB key, plug it in another Windows computer, and run the game from the USB drive, then remove the USB drive, but keep the game running flawlessly.

How could I do that?

Comment: This may not be possible in Unity as you have relatively little control over when and how stuff is loaded and stored in memory. It's also very dependent on the host computer's availability of RAM (especially for a 3D game)

Comment: So is it possible if I use RAMDRIVE?

Comment: you mean just a ram disk in general? If so, then if you store the entire game there obv it will all sit in ram

Comment: Have you TRIED removing the memory stick while the game is running? If the game does not load anything while it is running (like new levels or sounds), and it fits into ram completely, maybe it will work. But your question does not imply that you have tried already. If you have, can you explain what happened and what went wrong?

Comment: ^ can you explain what happened and what went wrong?

Comment: Store the game in the temp folder and use an independant on quit callback to delete the game afterwards. My question is though, why all this trouble in the first place? What are you trying to achieve? This request is bordering on possible malware/virus architecture.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this with a ram drive but at that point you might as well copy it to the host hard drive.

Comment: yes but I want to game disappear when turn off computer.

Comment: I _think_ you can handle this with an [OnApplicationQuit()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnApplicationQuit.html) function call